# How to deal with factor values in a data frame when building a reactive map widget on shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am currently developing a reactive map on Shiny. This map is basically a US map where a selectors enables the user to display different quality variables. The data frame used (called `data`)looks as follows (data here is randomised) :

```
head(data)
       state year  var1  var2      var3     var4    var5            var6    var7
1    Alabama 2020    4    8      12.00   454544  12.00             71-8     12
2   Arkansas 2020    4    1      12.00   454544  12.00             71-8     12
3    Arizona 2020    4    8      12.00   454544  12.00             11-2     12
4 California 2020    4    8      12.00   454544  12.00           others     12
5    Florida 2020    4    8      12.00   454544  12.00             71-9     12
6    Georgia 2020    4    8      12.00   454544  12.00           others     12
```

I am encountering an issue with the `var6` variable. Indeed, unlike the other variables such as `var1` or `var2` which are numeric, `var6` is a factor. I would like to color the map according to the different factor levels (in total 4 different levels). However, when I do so, I obtain some weird things: it colours the different states according to the level to which they belong (which is what I want) but instead of displaying the names of the levels in both the legend and the pop-up that appears when hovering the map with the mouse, it displays values 1, 2, 3, 4. I already tried to assign new names to the factor levels, yet it doesn't work.

Does anyone here have an idea about whether it is possible when building such a reactive map to account for other numeric and categorical types of value?

Answer (score 0):

In `sprintf("%s: %g",map$state, map$variableplot)`, the values of the factor variable `map$variableplot` are used (which are just numbers), but you want the `levels`. (Factor variables are just numbers, where each number is assigned a level. You can check it with `str(map$variableplot)`.) Try the below that extracts the levels when a factor is present:

```
variableplot_clean <- ifelse(is.factor(map$variableplot),
                             levels(map$variableplot), map$variableplot)

labels <- sprintf("%s: %s",map$state, variableplot_clean) %>%
  lapply(htmltools::HTML)
```

Comment: Thank you for for answer @starja. Unfortunately, this does not seem to solve my issue. After having added your code, the app still runs fine but this issue remains the same. The legend is still weird (shows sort of bins even though it makes no sense for levels) and when I hover my mouse on the state, it still displays values 1,2,3,4.

Comment: Can you provide a MRE (short running shiny app and data pasted as output from `dput`)? Thanks

Comment: I am sorry but I do not know how I am supposed to make a reproducible MRE as I have to include the shape file ?

Answer (score 0):

Since `color_leaf_grade` is a factor variable, you could use the [colorFactor](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.1.1/topics/colorNumeric) function to generate the palette. You can specify the color for each level in the factor set, like this:

```
pal <- colorFactor(palette = c("red","yellow","orange","green"),
                levels = c("31-1","11-2","others","factor4..."))
```

And then your addPolygons would look like this:

```
addPolygons(
    fillColor = ~pal(color_leaf_grade),
    color = "white",
    dashArray = "3",
    fillOpacity = 0.7,
    label = labels
  )
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The `colorFactor` seems like a good idea but unfortunately, when I use it, it applies to all other (numeric) variables and the inverse issue happens.